# CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95

Tags: mount, cifs

Trying to mount a shared drive at work via an `/etc/fstab` entry.

I can mount two of the three possible network shares with the following...

```
//SHAREDDATA02/WORK1    /mnt/work1  cifs        credentials=/etc/nfs_share.credentials,users,rw,uid=me,gid=me,sec=ntlm,noperm   0 0
//SHAREDDATA02/WORK2/USER /mnt/my_network   cifs    credentials=/etc/nfs_share.credentials,users,rw,uid=me,gid=me,sec=ntlm,noperm   0 0
```

...the third share is on a different (newer) server though and the following entry...

```
//UOSFSTORE/SHARED/XDRIVE /mnt/xdrive   cifs    credentials=/etc/nfs_share.credentials,users,rw,uid=me,gid=me,sec=ntlm,noperm    0 0
```

...results in the following error message...

```
# mount -v /mnt/xdrive
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=172.30.1.99,unc=\\UOSFSTORE\SHARED,sec=ntlm,noperm,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=cm1nds,prefixpath=XDRIVE,pass=********
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
# dmesg | tail -n1
[257463.335188] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

I've tried all of the possible `sec` options to no avail, so its not a difference in the security protocol implemented on the server.

Searching around I can't find anything on what the return code `-95` indicates/suggests.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I got this to work by adding min protocol = LANMAN1 in the global section for the server.

Answer (score 7):

I get into the same problem. 
For me work adding the option `vers=2.0`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your **client** uses the old **SMB1 protocol as default** and the newer **server only permits** from **SMB2 and on wards**.

I had the same error message on my Ubuntu 20.04 TLS (Client) after I updated my Ubuntu 18.04 server to 20.04. I had configured the client to use samba protocol version SMB1.

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

`dmesg` gave me a more precise message

```
CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers
CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

Since you haven't a version set in your configuration I assume your client uses SMB1 as default. Maybe setting the version to SMB2 with `vers=2.0` like [ceinmart](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530459/405964) said will fix that.

E.g:

```
//UOSFSTORE/SHARED/XDRIVE /mnt/xdrive   cifs    credentials=/etc/nfs_share.credentials,users,rw,uid=me,gid=me,sec=ntlm,noperm,vers=2.0   0 0
```

I suggest to update your smb client so it uses SMB2 or newer as default.

Comment: for me the return code was -22, and no hint to the wrong version in dmesg. Nevertheless, adding the *vers* option worked

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I had

```
//192.168.1.1/sda1 /mnt/hd2 cifs guest,nodfs
```

Inside of my `/etc/fstab`, and the underlying samba server (provided by openwrt) did not support `nodfs`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Credential file differences between `smbclient` and `mount.cifs`

Encountering same problem:

```
# smbclient -A /path/to/credential.cred //SERVER/SHARE -c ls | tail -n1
            6070936960 blocks of size 1024. 1832196388 blocks available
```

Everything is fine, but

```
# mount -vvv -t cifs -o  uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=path/to/credential.cred //SERVER/SHARE /mnt
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=1.2.3.4,unc=\\SERVER\SHARE,gid=1000,user= username,pass=******
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

... I've noticed the **space** before *`username`*! Reviewing my credential:

> ```
> username = username
> password = such1strongPassword
> ```

Tried to remove spaces:

```
# sed -e 's/ //g' -i /path/to/credential.cred
```

Did the job!!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this specify related to your case, but in my case I tried to secure my SAMBA share from [WannaCry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack) so I set the option `min protocol` to `SMB2`

```
[global]
...
min protocol = SMB2
```

But after that I was not able to access my shares from Kodi and simple `mount.cifs` command didn't help.

So I'm including this in case some else will come across this question via search like I did.